# Plot numpy.histogram2d()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am wondering if it is maybe possible to plot the output of numpy.histogram2d() using matplotlib.pyplot.hist2d? In the one-dimensional case, this can be done by using:

```
counts, bins = np.histogram(something, bins=no_bins, range=(range_min, range_max))

plt.hist(bins[:-1], bins, weights=counts)
```

Is there a similar solution for the two-dimensional case? I do not want to plot the 2d histo with the methods suggested on https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html
The idea behind this is that I would like to apply some corrections to the inital histogram (i.e. bin-by-bin background subtraction using data from another 2d histogram) and then plot the corrected histogram.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: maybe `plt.contourf`

Answer (score 0):

Plotting 2d histograms is typically done with [imshow()](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html). If you're used to ROOT or some other plotting libraries, be especially careful what argument you give for `origin` and `extent`.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution works as expected:

```
counts_bkg, bins_x_bkg, bins_y_bkg = np.histogram2d(x_bkg, y_bkg, bins=(x_bins, ybins))
counts, bins_x, bins_y = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(x_bins, y_bins))

diff = counts - counts_bkg
diffT = diff.T

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
pc = ax.pcolorfast(bins_x, bins_y, diffT)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

[In the docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram2d.html), you can find three examples of how to plot the output from `np.histogram2d()` using the *matplotlib* functions `imshow`, `pcolormesh` and `NonUniformImage`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I googled my way here. I am going to write here what worked for me, just in case, some else finds themselves in similar situtation.

I was looking at the source code of pyplot, where I found reference to axes class. The hist2d funtion is actually defined in 'matplotlib/axes/_axes.py'.
There I found hist2d calls np.histogram2s and then uses the xedges, yedges and bins in plt.pcolormesh as follow:

```
pc = self.pcolormesh(xedges, yedges, h.T, **kwargs)
```

Remember there is no option to use keywords 'Range', 'density' and 'bins' in pcolormesh but these are taken into account by the np.histogram2d function.

TL;DR: Using pcolormesh is the simplest way for plotting 2D histogram from the output of np.histogram2d.